# Xcode C++ error with game states

Tags: c++, xcode, state, sfml

So I wanted to make a game with really clean code and good organization. Looking into game states I found this site: http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/

Using his templates, I have this so far:

GameState.hpp

```
#ifndef Rect_Game_GameState_hpp
#define Rect_Game_GameState_hpp

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "GameEngine.hpp"

class GameEngine;

class GameState {

public:
    virtual void Init() = 0;
    virtual void Cleanup() = 0;

    virtual void Pause() = 0;
    virtual void Resume() = 0;

    virtual void HandleEvents(GameEngine* game) = 0;
    virtual void Update(GameEngine* game) = 0;
    virtual void Draw(GameEngine* game) = 0;

    virtual void ChangeState(GameEngine* game, GameState* state);

private: 
    GameState() { }
};

#endif
```

TitleScreenState.hpp

```
#ifdef Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp
#def Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "GameState.hpp"
#include "GameEngine.hpp"

class TitleScreenState : public GameState {

public:
    void Init();
    void Cleanup();

    void Pause();
    void Resume();

    void HandleEvents(GameEngine* engine);
    void Update(GameEngine* engine);
    void Draw(GameEngine* engine);

    void ChangeState(GameEngine* engine, GameState* state);

    static TitleScreenState* Instance();

private:

    TitleScreenState() {}

    static TitleScreenState* titleScreenInstance;

    sf::RenderWindow* window;

    int mouseX;
    int mouseY;

    Button* playButton;

};

#endif
```

And then the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'TitleScreenState'" appears every time I try to implement the functions. It's not auto-completing "TitleScreenState" either. Any suggestions?

TitleScreenState.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GameEngine.hpp"
#include "GameState.hpp"
#include "TitleScreenState.hpp"
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"



void TitleScreenState::Init()
{
    // Initialize values
    leftClick = false;
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;

    // Load title screen image
    sf::Texture titleImage;
    if (!titleImage.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "TitleScreen.png"))
        printf("could not load TitleScreen.png");

    sf::Sprite titleScreen;
    titleScreen.setTexture(titleImage);

    playButton = new Button("Play", 350, 220);

}
```

Comment: It should be #define Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp rather than #def Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp. Might be more problems there too though

Comment: Took me forever to see the difference, but good catch. I must have been tired. The error is still there though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is TitleScreenState.hpp:

```
#ifdef Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp
#def Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp
```

First, the `#ifdef` prevents the compiler from seeing the rest of the file, because `Rect_Game_TitleScreenState_hpp` hasn't been defined. Therefore, it should have been `#ifndef`. In addition, the `#def` should have been `#define`. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Aha. I fixed the define, but I didn't catch the 'n'. This fixed my main problem, now to correct the other errors.

Comment: @Jazzertron, what are the other errors? I haven't tried to compile your code.

Comment: Nothing related to this. Just fixing the other code now that this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched c++ in a while but it seems you have declared the default constructor has being private:

```
private:
   TitleScreenState() {}
```

If i'm not mistaken this means that you cant run:

```
void TitleScreenState::Init()
```

because it is a non static function that requires `TitleScreenState` to be instantiated and the default controller is private :S, so everywhere where you have `new TitleScreenState()` you will get that error, because effectivly no public `TitleScreenState` is available giving the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'TitleScreenState'`

have you tried to move it to public?

```
public:
   TitleScreenState() {}
```

Comment: I did it that way because I think it's how the Singleton pattern goes. i.e. that you'll only ever instantiate it once, so the constructor should be hidden and in place of it should be a method that returns a static instance (TitleScreen::Instance())

Comment: yes but if you expect to do "new BlaBlaBla()" you need to have a public constructor. you probably want a static function that runs the private constructor